# Colab isn't using GPU for training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm training a custom model on GTSRB dataset for traffic sign recognition on Google Colab. I've successfully built my model, But when I'm training my model it runs on CPU instead of GPU. I've selected GPU runtime earlier and using mirrored strategy using keras-Tensorflow. Any help will be appreciated. I'm adding snippets of my code.

```
with strategy.scope():

  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, 
  horizontal_flip=False)
  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/Train',target_size= 
  (64, 64),batch_size=32,class_mode='categorical')
  validation_generator = 
  test_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory='/content/drive/MyDrive/validation', target_size= 
  (64, 64), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')
  checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
  cp_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1, 
  save_freq='epoch')

with strategy.scope():
  model = training(classes)
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4),metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=200, epochs=50, validation_data=validation_generator, 
validation_steps=100, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

while training I've checked the GPU and CPU usage which is shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: What evidence do you have that the GPU is not  being used? You cannot infer this by looking at the information you provided (GPU RAM does not tell you much)

Comment: My model is taking long time to get train. like around 45 mins for 200 steps for the starting epoch(excluding validation).

Comment: Unfortunately that is not evidence that the GPU is not being used, people made correct suggestions like using nvidia-smi to get GPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the GPU while the model is being run using the command
`nvidia-smi`.

Comment: i have checked usage using wandb command while training! its only showing cpu threads usage.

Comment: I've Checked GPU usage while training by running 'wandb' command. It's not showing GPU anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this before multiple times with multiple platforms (Kaggle, Colab) but only managed to solve this once. In that case, it was due to tensorflow_gpu (gpu version of tensorflow) not being installed when I switched tensorflow versions. You can check the version of tensorflow_gpu and the version of tensorflow that is installed. Make sure that the versions are the same. This may be totally off the mark or it might work for you.

Comment: I'm using tf>2.0 and it don't have tf-gpu.